# React Native - Invalid hook call using useRef

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm trying to use useRef() in one of my compononents in React Native, but I keep getting the

> Component Exception: Invalid Hook Call. Hooks can only be called
> inside of the body of a function component

My component:

```
import React, { createRef, useRef } from 'react';
import { Animated, View } from 'react-native';

const BottomTabMenu: React.FC = ({ navigation, state: { routeNames } }) => {

  const xPosition = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;


  return (
    <Container>

      <Animated.View style={{ 
          position: 'absolute', left: 37, top: 32,
          transform: [
            {
              translateX: xPosition
            }
          ]
       }}>
        <LinearGradient
          start={{ x: 0, y: 0 }} end={{ x: 1, y: 0 }}
          colors={['#FF151B', '#AA0089']}
          style={{
            height: 40, width: 50, borderRadius: 20 }}>
        </LinearGradient>
      </Animated.View>


      <BottomTabMenuItem icon={require('../assets/performance.png')} title="Performance" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Performance')} />
      <BottomTabMenuItem icon={require('../assets/wallet.png')} title="Carteira" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Wallet')} />
      <BottomTabMenuItem icon={require('../assets/transactions.png')} title="Extrato" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Transactions')} />
      <BottomTabMenuItem icon={require('../assets/settings.png')} title="Ajustes" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Settings')} />

    </Container>
  )
}
```

I have used useRef in other components without any issue.. This one in particular is a bottom tab tab..

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should use `.current` when you are accessing the value, not when you call `useRef()`. Try: `const xPosition = useRef(new Animated.Value(0));` and then `transform: [ { translateX: xPosition.current } ]`. Does that solve your issue?

Comment: Hey @CharlesKornoelje unfortunately it did not resolve the issue.. the .current in the useRef I got from the documentation at https://reactnative.dev/docs/animated

Comment: I stand corrected. I'll look into this a little further, but perhaps someone else will provide a working answer.

Comment: Hey Bruno, I was able to reproduce the functionality, I believe, without error in an [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@charkour/intrigued-carrot) (on the right side, click web to view it). I don't think I have the knowledge to solve your issue, but the code you provided doesn't seem to be a problem. I would start by looking where your `<BottomTabMenu />` component is being used and trouble-shoot from there. Sorry I couldn't help fully.

Comment: If you are using a different method of calling `<BottomTabMenu />` such as `{BottomTabMenu()}` then you'll get the error you're experiencing.

Comment: Hey @CharlesKornoelje many thanks for helping, you actually guided in the right direction.. I was using the Tab.Navigator component incorrectly.. I'll post the solution below

Comment: Glad to help.  I'll check it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was calling this component in a wrong manner in the BottomTabNavigator component..

BEFORE:

```
<TabMenu.Navigator initialRouteName="Performance" tabBar={BottomTabMenu}>
  <TabMenu.Screen name="Performance" component={Performance} />
  <TabMenu.Screen name="Wallet" component={Wallet} />
  <TabMenu.Screen name="Transactions" component={Transactions} />
  <TabMenu.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings} />
</TabMenu.Navigator>
```

AFTER:

```
<TabMenu.Navigator initialRouteName="Performance" tabBar={props => <BottomTabMenu {...props} />}>
  <TabMenu.Screen name="Performance" component={Performance} />
  <TabMenu.Screen name="Wallet" component={Wallet} />
  <TabMenu.Screen name="Transactions" component={Transactions} />
  <TabMenu.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings} />
</TabMenu.Navigator>
```

The piece of code `tabBar={props => <BottomTabMenu {...props} />}` did the trick..

Thanks @CharlesKornoelje and @RowanX for helping

Answer (score 0):

Try to do the following:

```
  const xPosition = React.useRef<HTMLElement | null>( new Animated.Value(0)).current
```

`useRef` receives types is the same as the useState hook. You just have to pass it into the <>.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't solve the issue.. :/ still get the same exception, also I had to change it to useReact<Animated.Value> otherwise it would not compile..